# What are the ways to invest in cobalt, lithium, and nickel?

Tags: investing, trading, futures, commodities, metals

How to invest in metals like cobalt, lithium, and nickel? I am not interested in investing in firms that are mining them but in investing in metals directly (via futures or other instruments). Consider two scenarios:

1. Total money for investing is $20,000.
2. Total money for investing is $200,000.

Comment: Investing in futures is not investing directly in metals, but in derivatives. Investing directly in metals needs warehouse space and shipping facilities.

Comment: @MikeScott I am not expert in economics so there can be some mistakes in terms. But I wrote "(futures or other ways)" to clarify that I don't mean "warehouse space and shipping facilities".

Comment: You may want to read this [article](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-cobalt27-ipo-ahome/psst-wanna-buy-some-cobalt-just-dont-tell-the-auto-guys-andy-home-idUSKBN19Q2FC).

Comment: You've practically answered your own question with your 2nd question https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/89093/what-is-the-minimum-amount-of-money-that-is-needed-to-start-trading-in-the-londo?rq=1 , the only unknown is, is 20k$ enough to set up an account...

Comment: @DanubianSailor LME is one of the way but I also want to know about other ways too if they exist.

Comment: @Rodrigo de Azevedo I see that you are interested too. Check this question and its comments too https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/89093/what-is-the-minimum-amount-of-money-that-is-needed-to-start-trading-in-the-londo?noredirect=1#comment155334_89093

Comment: You can't invest in metals, you can only speculate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is not so clear cut as you may like, but all depends on your aversion to risk and your financial well-being.

At both $20,000 and $200,000 you can invest in metals, it just depends on what you're willing to lose. That's right, even if metals are pretty non-volatile, when you invest money you need to be prepared to take a loss. If losing major portions of your initial investment (i.e. $20,000 or $200,000) would cause you financial distress then I would suggest not investing that money.

If you are looking to trade in the United States, the [American Metals Market](http://www.amm.com/) looks like a good place to start. There is also the [APMEX](https://www.apmex.com/) and  the [American Metal XChange](https://amxinc.com/).

In london there is the London Metals exchange, a comprehensive list of fees, pricing, membership and FAQ's are located [HERE](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/89093/what-is-the-minimum-amount-of-money-that-is-needed-to-start-trading-in-the-londo/89391#89391) on another one of my answers.

To answer your question directly, to invest in metals you can go through popular exchanges like the ones I've linked, or you can try to find local traders. In the end you will probably need some sort of storage, as you are buying and selling physical items. Sometimes you can find places that will keep metals for you for a small fee.

If you are looking to make money off of the rise in these commodity prices, I would suggest investing in mining companies (even though I know you said you didn't want to). They are advantageous in a few ways:

1) You have no physical property to keep safe and secured, and no shipping charges to worry about.

2) Trading shares is much more easily and readily done than trading physical materials. You need to think about the *liquidity* of your assets.

3) Mining stocks are found in every market around the world, making it easy to invest where you are.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

With conditions given (zero knowledge and no aims) simply buy non-leverage ETF (no short, no long-leverage, no credit risks).